# Hybrid \$\pi\$ Model vs. T-Model Input Resistance (MOSFET)

Tags: mosfet, resistance, impedance, input-impedance

[image: Pi Model]

[image: T model]

If the hybrid-\$\pi\$ model and T-Model are equivalent models, why does the hybrid-\$\pi\$ model have an infinite input impedance and the T model has an input impedance of \$1/g_m\$ assuming \$\alpha=1\$.

Answer (score 5):

To find the input resistance, the procedure is to apply a test voltage \$v_t\$ to the input terminal (the gate). With the source node as our reference voltage \$v_t\$ is simply \$v_{gs}\$ (voltage from gate to source). The input resistance \$R_i\$ is then the ratio of the test voltage divided by the current \$i_t\$ supplied by the test voltage:

$$R_i = \frac{v_t}{i_t}$$

In this case \$i_t\$ is the current flowing from the gate node to the T junction (between the dependent current source and \$r_s\$).

The dependent current source \$i_s\$ in the MOSFET T-model is equal to \$g_m v_{gs}\$ (just like the hybrid-\$\pi\$ model). By Ohm's Law the current from gate to source (through \$r_s\$) is

$$i_{gs} = \frac{v_{gs}}{r_{s}} = \frac{v_{gs}}{1/g_m} = g_m v_{gs}$$

Since \$i_s = i_{gs}\$ it must be true by KCL that \$i_t = 0\$ no matter what the input voltage \$v_t\$ is. Therefore

$$R_i = \frac{v_t}{i_t} = \frac{v_t}{0} = \infty$$

The input resistance for the T-model is infinite, just as it is for the hybrid-\$\pi\$ model. It is *not* equal to \$1/g_m\$.

Comment: That does not make sense. When I connect a source with a sorce resitance to the Pi model, I get an infinite impedance, but now if I again connect the source and source resistance to a T model, I get an input impedance of 1/gm. I know 0 current passes through the gate. I am sorry, I probably don't understand the concept of input impedance.

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain the procedure for finding the input resistance in more detail. The input resistance is not 1/gm -- it is infinite, just like the hybrid-\$\pi\$ model.

Answer (score 2):

It should be emphasized on the schematic that \$i_s = g_mv_{gs}\$.

Note that the current passing through resistor \$r_s\$ will always be:
$$
i_{r_s} = v_{gs} / r_s = v_{gs}\times g_m = i_s,
$$

irrespective of where any source signal gets applied.

Since \$i_s=i_{r_s}\$, then it must be that \$i_g=0 \$, because of KCL.

If current cannot flow into a node from an applied voltage source signal, that means the resistance seen from the perspective of that source to the node is infinite.

**OR**

You could replace \$r_s\$ by a voltage controlled current source - proportional to its own voltage drop (because that is what a resistor actually models). The transconductance of a resistor is just the inverse of the resistance. You'll see that both vccs's in series, always have the same current: \$g_mv_{gs}\$.

This again implies that \$i_g=0\$.

Answer (score 0):

Viewing the NMOSFET from a "black box perspective", we know that current flows from the drain to source in this configuration. So we can't have that infinite input impedance gap that the Hybrid \$\pi\$ Model has if we want to make a usable vertical configuration (a T Model).

Thankfully the voltage-controlled current source from the \$\pi\$ model takes care of the current from the drain to the gate. Now what about the current from the gate to the source? We know there's a voltage drop (\$v_{gs}\$) and a current (\$i_{d}\$) there. Current with a voltage drop means there's a resistance present.

\$r_s = \frac{v_{g} - v_{s}}{i_{s}}=\frac{v_{gs}}{i_{d}} = \frac{v_{gs}}{g_{m}v_{gs}} = \frac{1}{g_{m}}\$

So we get:

\$r_{s} = \frac{1}{g_{m}}\$